# What is the usage of "How serious"?

Tags: phrase-usage

> How serious was the accident happened nearby yesterday?

Is the usage of "how serious" correct?

Comment: *How serious* is fine, but in all but the most casual English the relative clause requires a relativizer (*that* or *which*) when its missing term is the subject.

Answer (score 1):

This particular usage of *how* is as follows:

**how + adjective + be** -> used to ask about the **intensity** of an adjective related to a noun.

> How serious was the problem?
>
> How serious was the accident?

Source: [Advanced Grammar: For Academic Writing](https://books.google.rs/books?id=6jQ3AgAAQBAJ&pg=PA57&dq=%22how+serious+was%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=aTF3Ve_lN4jIsQGCnqeQBA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22how%20serious%20was%22&f=false) by Richard Stevenson

One could reply:

**very** serious, not very serious, not particularly serious etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is the correct.. Although you need to add a "that" after accident to make the sentence grammatically correct.

Comment: Stoney said what you said, but he put a comment there. Doesn't this mean that this much can't make a good answer? This is better as a comment unless you be more elaborate.